# Accents in uploaded file being replaced with '?'

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, character-encoding, diacritics

I am building a data import tool for the admin section of a website I am working on. The data is in both French and English, and contains many accented characters. Whenever I attempt to upload a file, parse the data, and store it in my MySQL database, the accents are replaced with '?'.

I have text files containing data (charset is iso-8859-1) which I upload to my server using CodeIgniter's file upload library. I then read the file in PHP.

My code is similar to this:

```
$this->upload->do_upload()
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

$fileHandle = fopen($data['upload_data']['full_path'], "r");

while (($line = fgets($fileHandle)) !== false) {
    echo $line;
}
```

This produces lines with accents replaced with '?'. Everything else is correct.

If I download my uploaded file from my server over FTP, the charset is still iso-8850-1, but a diff reveals that the file has changed. However, if I open the file in TextEdit, it displays properly.

I attempted to use PHP's `stream_encoding` method to explicitly set my file stream to iso-8859-1, but my build of PHP does not have the method.

After running out of ideas, I tried wrapping my strings in both `utf8_encode` and `utf8_decode`. Neither worked.

If anyone has any suggestions about things I could try, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Important to see if the corruption is happening before or after the query is being issued to mySQL. There are too many possible things happening here to be able to pinpoint it. Are you able to output your MySql to check this?

Assuming that your query IS properly formed (no corruption at the stage the query is being outputted) there are a couple of things that you should check.

1. What is the character encoding of the database itself? (collation)
2. What is the Charset of the connection - this may not be set up correctly in your mysql config and can be manually set using the 'SET NAMES' command

In my own application I issue a 'SET NAMES utf8' as my first query after establishing a connection as I am unable to change the MySQL config.

See this.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

**Edit:** If the issue is not related to mysql I'd check the following

1. You say the encoding of the file is 'charset is iso-8859-1' - can I ask how you are sure of this?
2. What happens if you save the file itself as utf8 (Without BOM) and try to reprocess it?
3. What is the encoding of the *php* file that is performing the conversion? (What are you using to write your php - it may be 'managing' this for you in an undesired way)
4. (an aside) Are the files you are processing suitable for processing using fgetcsv instead?
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: If I directly echo out the strings being read in by fgets(), they have question marks instead of accents. I do not think the problem is related to MySQL.

Comment: I checked the charset of the file using `file -I <filepath>` on the command line. I am creating and editing the PHP files using Eclipse, and they are encoded as ascii. I am uploading files with Filezilla, but encoding appears to be preserved through that- when I download files I have previously uploaded, they still have their original charsets.

Comment: As per your #2 suggestion, I saved my original file with utf-8 encoding, and it worked. Since I cannot guarantee that my users will be using this charset, is there a way I can make the conversion when the file is uploaded?

Comment: Try and convert the encoding of the file. I use Notepad++ to do this as it allows simple conversion between ANSI/ utf8 etc. http://notepad-plus-plus.org/. In my experience 50% of problems with encoding are down to the source file being incorrectly encoded and 50% are to do with the database/connection. Open your file with NP++ (assuming you can use Windows) and choose 'convert to utf-8 without BOM' from the encoding menu. Save. Try to reupload. See how you get on.

Comment: @kissmyface it works properly when my uploaded file uses utf-8, but the files that will be uploaded are dumped from an external database that saves its export data with iso-8859-1 (which according to hakre supports French accents). If I convert the file, I need to convert it on my server.

Comment: @Katfish You may be able to use mb_convert_encoding() - though that will depend on whether the multibyte library is available in your environment. (You'll find out pretty quickly if you try and use the function and it is undefined) http://uk.php.net/function.mb-convert-encoding

Comment: @kissmyface I used mb_convert_encoding() to convert the string to iso-8859-1, and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Files uploaded to your server should be returned the same on download. That means, the encoding of the file (which is just a bunch of binary data) should not be changed. Instead you should take care that you are able to store the binary information of that file unchanged.

To achieve that with your database, create a BLOB field. That's the right column type for it. It's just binary data.

Assuming you're using MySQL, this is the reference: [The BLOB and TEXT Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html), look out for BLOB.

Comment: I am not storing the file in my database; just strings I read from the file.

Comment: What is the datatype of the field in the database?

Comment: The field in the database is text, but I have lost my accents before I store anything in the database. If I echo the strings as I read them from my file, they do not have accents.

Comment: Where do you echo them? Your browser? Have you checked if bytes are in order by using a [`hex_dump()` function](https://gist.github.com/1023318/721efb91a767de471f3d0636e59d69fca66066a6)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using iso-8859-1 instead of utf-8. In order to encode it in the correct charset, you should use the iconv function, like so:

`$output_string = iconv('utf-8", "utf-8//TRANSLIT", $input_string);`

iso-8859-1 does not have the encoding for any sort of accents.

It would be so much better if everything were utf-8, as it handles virtually every character known to man.

Comment: I just tried using iconv(), but it failed with the error 'Detected an illegal character in input string'. I also tried using iso-8859-1 as the input character set. If iso-8859-1 does not have any sort of accent encoding, how does it display accents? Do programs like TextEdit automatically convert the encoding before displaying it?

Comment: @Katfish: IIRC iso-8859-1 covers french accents. If you store files into the database you should store them as BLOB and deliver them as is with their "native" encoding. Don't mangle them as suggested in this answer before you store them in the database. Store them AS-IS.

Comment: @hakre I am only storing strings I read from my files in my database. Files are being deleted after I parse them.

Comment: If you store strings, they might get mangled by MySQL to match your database/table/column encoding (or even by the client for the connecting to your database). Store them into a BLOB field. A string in PHP is a binary string, so you're actually dealing with binary data.

Comment: @hakre If I use a BLOB field, will PHP still be able to read it as if it were a string?

Comment: Yes. All string in PHP *are* binary. This is no problem. Btw, you can use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to just read the whole file into a string.

Comment: @hakre I know, but each line of my file is a database row, and I need to deal with each one individually.

Comment: @Katfish: Then you should define the encoding needed for your organisation of data and make that visible to the user on the upload form which encoding is expected the file to be.